# fig.savefig outputs blank files in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am aware that this has been asked many times. I have read the relevant threads and tried to implement the suggestions, but nothing seems to work. Plots show just fine, but saving them yields blank files.

Here's my code:

```
for time_index in np.arange(hr_from,hr_to,1):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 10], subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                      linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='-')
    extent = [-11, 16, 39, 61] # latitude and longitude borders of the map
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    #
    # Other details of plotting omitted here
    #
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)
    fig.savefig("C:/maps.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

What am I missing?

Edit: if it's of any relevance, the output file type is PapyrusPlugin Class, which I've not heard of until now so don't know much about it

Comment: I'm not really sure why this happens, but I've fixed this problem before by just changing `fig.savefig()` to `plt.savefig`.

Comment: I've tried that too, still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why or how, but this is how I fixed it:

In this line of code,

fig.savefig("C:/maps.png", bbox_inches='tight')

I originally had strings in it like "%s". Instead of using %s I just used f-string and it started to save the plots correctly. I didn't expect this to cause an error at all, that's why I didn't even post the line as I originally wrote in my full script.